# How to calculate turbulence and similarity index with TraMineR?

Tags: traminer

I am new to sequence analysis and wondering whether TraMineR can calculate Elzinga's turbulence and similarity index or I should learn to use his CHESA software to do this? I appreciate any thoughts as I learn to do sequence analysis.

Comment: [Yes](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf). Users guides are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

The `seqST` TraMineR function computes Elzinga's turbulence.

As for Elzinga's similarity indices, you probably mean the non-aligning measures based on the number of matching or common subsequences. These measures are currently not available in the stable TraMineR version. They have been coded but are still in test.